# How to use pandas groupby and apply lambda to evaluate a boolean condition

Tags: lambda, apply, multi-index, pandas-groupby

I've been teaching myself python using stock data but I've been stuck on this issue. I'm trying to identify a moving average cross-over. I'm working with daily data in a pandas MultiIndex DataFrame. Below is a snippet of the data structure I'm working with.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'date': pd.Series(['2016-1-4', '2016-1-4', '2016-1-4', 
                           '2016-1-5', '2016-1-5', '2016-1-5', 
                           '2016-1-6', '2016-1-6', '2016-1-6']),
        'ticker': pd.Series(['NYMX', 'EVAR', 'PMV', 
                             'NYMX', 'EVAR', 'PMV', 
                             'NYMX', 'EVAR', 'PMV']),
        'twohundredsma': pd.Series([2.3, 3.58, 0.458, 
                                    2.31, 3.56, 0.459, 
                                    2.32, 3.55, 0.46]),
        'fiveema': pd.Series([2.33, 1.31, 0.54, 
                              2.33, 1.28, 0.54, 
                              2.3, 1.25, 0.54])}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index(['date', 'ticker'], inplace=True)
```

A cross-over can be identified by taking the difference between the two moving averages and using `shift` to check for a change in sign from the previous day. I've tested this approach (without groupby) and it works great, providing a `True` value whenever a crossover has occurred.

However, the issue I'm having is with using the `groupby` function to apply this function to each stock ticker. My initial approach was to use an `apply` `lambda` function. The code below adds the 2 new columns but the "five200bull" column is filled with "nan" values with no errors being thrown.

```
def five_cross(df):
    df['fiveminus200'] = df['fiveema'] - df['twohundredsma']    

    df['five200bull'] = df.groupby(level='ticker').apply(lambda x: 
      np.sign(x['fiveminus200'])!=np.sign(x['fiveminus200'].shift(1)))
```

So I tried a different approach where I passed each ticker as a dataframe to a separate function. This approach was much slower when working with a large dataframe, but this didn't work either.

```
def add_five_bull(df):
    df['five200bull'] = np.sign(df['fiveminus200']) != np.sign(df['fiveminus200'].shift(1))

def five_cross(df):
    df['fiveminus200'] = df['fiveema'] - df['twohundredsma']    

    # group by ticker
    grouped = df.groupby(level='ticker')

    # pass each ticker in a df to function
    for tick, group in grouped:
        add_five_bull(group)
```

With this approach the "five200bull" column is never appended to the df and I receive the infamous `SettingWithCopyWarning`. I tried adding `df.loc[:, 'fiveminus200']` to the `add_five_bull` function but other than taking much longer with a large dataset, it didn't appear to have any result.

Obviously there's some flaw in my logic and I would appreciate any help in resolving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need parameter `group_keys=False` for remove appending new level in output - then data are aliged. Also [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) return first value `NaN` per group, so `np.sign` raise warning:

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sign
>     np.sign(x['fiveminus200'])!=np.sign(x['fiveminus200'].shift(1)))

Solution is replace `NaN` to some value, e.g. `False` or `True` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
def five_cross(df):
    df['fiveminus200'] = df['fiveema'] - df['twohundredsma']    

    df['five200bull'] = df.groupby(level='ticker', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: 
      np.sign(x['fiveminus200'])!=np.sign(x['fiveminus200'].shift(1).fillna(False)))
    return df  

print (five_cross(df))
                   fiveema  twohundredsma  fiveminus200  five200bull
date       ticker                                                   
2016-01-04 NYMX       2.33          2.300         0.030         True
           EVAR       1.31          3.580        -2.270         True
           PMV        0.54          0.458         0.082         True
2016-01-05 NYMX       2.33          2.310         0.020        False
           EVAR       1.28          3.560        -2.280        False
           PMV        0.54          0.459         0.081        False
2016-01-06 NYMX       2.30          2.320        -0.020         True
           EVAR       1.25          3.550        -2.300        False
           PMV        0.54          0.460         0.080        False
```

---

```
def five_cross(df):
    df['fiveminus200'] = df['fiveema'] - df['twohundredsma']    

    df1 = df.groupby(level='ticker').apply(lambda x: 
      np.sign(x['fiveminus200'])!=np.sign(x['fiveminus200'].shift(1).fillna(False)))
    return df1 

print (five_cross(df))
ticker  date        ticker
EVAR    2016-01-04  EVAR       True
        2016-01-05  EVAR      False
        2016-01-06  EVAR      False
NYMX    2016-01-04  NYMX       True
        2016-01-05  NYMX      False
        2016-01-06  NYMX       True
PMV     2016-01-04  PMV        True
        2016-01-05  PMV       False
        2016-01-06  PMV       False
Name: fiveminus200, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks, the `group_keys=False` was exactly what I needed! I checked the docs and it clearly says to use it when calling `apply` but I missed it. The `fillna` doesn't appear to do anything. The first row returns `True` whether I put it in or not.